# Change the name of groups of values if duplicated in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains samples of time series data:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date1', 'date2', 'date3'], 'cat': ['cat1', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat2', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat3', 'cat3', 'cat3'], 'value': [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 9, 1, 7, 3, 2]})
```

Because the data is sample data, the values of the first and second observations of date1,cat1 are not necessarily the same. I want to relabel the values in the cat column so that in the second group of cat1 values, the category name is cat1_2 (cat1_3 for the third instance and cat2_2 for the second group of cat2 and so on). Is there a way to use pandas to do this? I was experimenting with using

```
data[data.duplicated(subset=['date', 'cat'])]
```

to identify the later groups, but have not yet had any success in achieving what I want. Thanks!

Comment: `data['cat'] = data['cat'] + '_' + data.groupby(['date','cat']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)`?

Comment: worked perfectly! if you post as an answer, I can accept it